# Product of an $L^\infty$ function and an $L^1$ function is integrable

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

For every $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R^n})$ let

$$
\hat{f} : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{C}, \quad
\hat{f}(\xi) 
:= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) \exp{(-i \langle x, \xi \rangle)} \;\mathrm{d}x
$$

be the Fourier Transform of $f$ with respect to the Lebesgue-measure.

One can show, that $\hat{f} \in L^\infty$ from the following inequality
$$
\tag{$\ast$} \| \hat f \|_\infty \leq \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} \; \|f\|_1.
$$

Another theorem states that for $f,g \in L_1(\mathbb{R^n})$ the functions $\hat{f}g$ and $f \hat{g}$ are integrable with

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \hat{f}(x)g(x) \;\mathrm{d}x
=
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y)\hat{g}(y)  \;\mathrm{d}y.
$$

The proof makes use of Fubini's theorem, therefore the integrability of $\hat{f}g$ and $f\hat{g}$ is crucial. My coursenotes say that integrability follows from ($\ast$), but I am not sure how to do this. Here is my attempt at a proof:

I need to show that $\| \hat{f}g \|_1 < \infty$. One could calculate

$$
\| \hat{f}g \|_1 
= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} | \hat{f} g | \; \mathrm{d}x
\leq \|\hat{f}\|_{\infty} \|g \|_1
< \infty
$$

and use the fact that $\hat{f} \in L_\infty$, but am I correctly using the monotonicity of the Lebesgue-Integral? $|\hat{f}| \leq \|\hat{f}\|_\infty$ is only true almost everywhere.

Comment: Null sets can be ignored for the purposes of integration. Apart from that, if $f\in L^1$, then $\hat{f} \in C_0$, so it is bounded on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Yes your inequality is correct. It is just Hölder's inequality (with p=1).

Comment: $\hat{f}$ is continuous, so actually $|\hat{f}| \le \|\hat{f}\|_{L^\infty}$ everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you've used it correctly.

It's true that $|\hat{f}| \le \|f\|_{L^\infty}$ only almost everywhere, but that is sufficient for your conclusion.  To see why, let $A = \{|\hat{f}| \le \|f\|_{L^\infty}\}$, and break your integral into two integrals, over the sets $A$ and $A^c$.  Then note that $A^c$ has measure zero.

Intuitively, the Lebesgue integral ignores null sets, so for the purposes of integration, you should expect that an "almost everywhere" statement is just as good as "everywhere".